# Data from Cloudpage to another Cloudpage

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

Is it possible to work with data using AMPscript to create this flow?

e-mail -> cloudpage -> cloudpage

I'm working with this flow where i have a hidden attribute in e-mail -> cloudpage. 
And my question is if possible to the same data goes to the second page when the customer click in submit (the customer will redirect to another cloudpage when clicks submit).

If is not clear sorry, I will update the question here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [CloudPagesURL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/cloudpagesurl.htm) pass data from the email to the CloudPage and use the [RequestParameter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/requestparameter.htm) AMPscript function to retrieve the data (GET and POST method). Or you can use [QueryParameter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/queryparameter.htm) function (GET method).

```
%%[
set @subKey = RequestParameter("_subscriberKey")
]%%
```

For data from CloudPage to CloudPage, a simple form input and `RequestParameter` should be enough to get you to pass the hidden attribute.

```
<form action="http://cloudpage" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="whatever" value="whatever">
</form>
```

Comment: Hello, @Jackson Thanks for attention. I have one issue that at same time i want to update a DE and pass the data from cloudpage to another cloud page; When i change the "<form action="http://cloudpage" method="post">" the Update Data Extension does not works :?

Comment: @JoaoMarano you’ll need to use the UpsertData function to update the data extension. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/upsertdata.htm